# Ionic1: Problems building app to versions previous to android 6

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app built on android,i´ve been struggling with the instalations of signed APK on devices with android 5. The phone doesn't install the app, but I don´t get any error of why. When I installed the APK on devices with android greater that 5 like 6 or 7 the app works correctly.

I try to change android target to 22, modified the main **config.xml** with next lines:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
</platform>
```

But when I try to add the platform cordova uses android target 23

```
$ ionic cordova platform add android@5.1.1
> cordova platform add android@5.1.1 --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@5.1.1

Adding android project...

Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

        Path: platforms\android

        Package: app.Frenzy

        Name: Frenzy
        Activity: MainActivity

        Android target: android-23
```

Tried modifying **project.properties** file manualy and set android target to 22 but when i change this value i can't continue building my apk. I received next error:

```
C:\Users\Ludwin Garcia\Desktop\frenzy\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaActivity.java:493: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
5 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I began with this problem when I added **cordova-plugin-nativeaudio** because my client requested that he need to add souds to the app. The client doesn´t want to change everything to a version of 6 and above, given that we will loose many existing customers which operate with android 5.

NOTE: When I use **cordova run android** i can execute my app on devices with android 5, the problem arises when i am trying to config my APK to upload to playstore.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />` as a direct child of the widget tag, at the same level as the platform tag.

Comment: Hi, I tried to move the lines and now cordova uses android target 25.